# javascript / for-loop even and odd letters from text

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to select even letters and odd letters from text, console.log show mi
(199) [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '....  How can I fix it ?

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //console.log(newText)  ok

  let evenletters = []

  for (let i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
    if(newText[i] % 2 === 0) {
      evenletters.push(newText[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(evenletters)
})
```

Comment: What does `newText` contain? And assuming (from the name) it is text, why do you use the remainder operator (`%`) on it?

Comment: const p = document.querySelector('p')
let newText = p.textContent

Comment: const p = document.querySelector('p')

Comment: let newText = p.textContent

Comment: Alright, so it is indeed text. Say I enter "Test", then the first iteration of your loop `newText[i]` will be "T". What do you expect `'T' % 2` to do?

Comment: @pete Just update your question to have it make more sense so that it's actually runnable, don't add a bunch of comments. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are coming from C or another language that can treat a char as an int.  What you want to do in JS is use `.charCodeAt`

```js
let evenletters = []
let newText = 'Hello there how are you?'
  for (let i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
    if(newText.charCodeAt(i) % 2 === 0) {
      evenletters.push(newText[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(evenletters)
```

Comment: @pete Are you certain the outcome is what you expect it to be? I expected you to want to log every other character in the string.

Comment: isn't the letter "H" an odd letter being the first?

Comment: I don't think he's trying to get characters at even/odd indexes.  He's trying to get even/odd "characters" - those with an even or odd char code.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It can be simplified with the `Array.reduce()` method after using the spread operator to convert the string to an array like this: `let evenLetters = [...newText].reduce((a, c) => (c.charCodeAt(0) % 2 == 0 ? a.push(c) : a, a), []);`